# Add subview on a parent drawn through UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, mask, uibezierpath

I've a custom UITabBar. Its bar has a simple but customised shape: its height is bigger then default one, has rounded corners and (important) a shadow layer on the top.
The result is this:
[image: CustomTabBar]

Now I've to add an element that shows the selected section on the top of the bar, to achieve this:
[image: The goal]

The problem is that no matter the way I choose to add this element (add a subview to the bar or add a new sublayer) but the new element **will always be drawn outside the corners**. I suppose this is because I can't enable the clipping mask (if I enable the clipping mask I'll kill the shadow and also, more important, the bezierpath)
[image]

Do you have any tips for this?
Basically, the goal should be:

**have an element that moves horizontally (animated) but cannot be drawn outside the parent (the tabbar)**

Actually, the code to draw the custom tabBar is:

```
class CustomTabBar: UITabBar {

    /// The layer that defines the custom shape
    private var shapeLayer: CALayer?
    /// The radius for the border of the bar
    var borderRadius: CGFloat = 0

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // aspect and shadow
        isTranslucent       = false
        backgroundColor     = UIColor.white
        tintColor           = AZTheme.PaletteColor.primaryColor
        shadowImage         = nil
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowColor   = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1
        layer.shadowOffset  = CGSize(width: 0, height: -1)
        layer.shadowRadius  = 10
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        drawShape()
    }

    /// Draw and apply the custom shape to the bar
    func drawShape() {
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = createPath()
        shapeLayer.fillColor = AZTheme.tabBarControllerBackgroundColor.cgColor

        if let oldShapeLayer = self.shapeLayer {
            self.layer.replaceSublayer(oldShapeLayer, with: shapeLayer)
        } else {
            self.layer.insertSublayer(shapeLayer, at: 0)
        }

        self.shapeLayer = shapeLayer
    }
}

// MARK: - Private functions
extension CustomTabBar {
    /// Return the custom shape for the bar
    internal func createPath() -> CGPath {
        let height: CGFloat = self.frame.height
        let path = UIBezierPath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: borderRadius, y: 0), radius: borderRadius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi, endAngle: CGFloat.pi * (3/2), clockwise: true)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.width - borderRadius, y: -borderRadius))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.width - borderRadius, y: 0), radius: borderRadius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi * (3/2), endAngle: 0, clockwise: true)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.width, y: height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: height))
        path.close()

        return path.cgPath
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved splitting the owner of custom shape from the owner of the shadow in 2 different views. So I'm using 3 views achieve the goal.

```
CustomTabBar: has default size and casts shadow with offset.
|
└ SelectorContainer: is a view with custom shape (BezierPath) that is
  positioned on the top of the TabBar to graphically "extend" the view
  and have the feeling of a bigger TabBar. It has rounded corners on
  the top-right, top-left margin. MaskToBounds enabled.
  |
  └ Selector: simple view that change the its origin through animation.
```

[See the result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUdy6.jpg)

The code:

````swift
class CustomTabBar: UITabBar {

    /// The corner radius value for the top-left, top-right corners of the TabBar
    var borderRadius: CGFloat = 0

    /// Who is containing the selector. Is a subview of the TabBar.
    private var selectorParent: UIView?
    /// Who moves itself following the current section. Is a subview of ```selectorParent```.
    private var selector: UIView?
    /// The height of the ```selector```
    private var selectorHeight: CGFloat = 5
    /// The number of sections handled by the TabBarController.
    private var numberOfSections: Int = 0

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        isTranslucent       = false
        backgroundColor     = UIColor.white
        tintColor           = AZTheme.PaletteColor.primaryColor
        shadowImage         = nil
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowColor   = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1
        layer.shadowOffset  = CGSize(width: 0, height: -1)
        layer.shadowRadius  = 10
    }
}

// MARK: - Private functions
extension CustomTabBar {
    /// Create the selector element on the top of the TabBar
    func setupSelectorView(numberOfSections: Int) {
        self.numberOfSections = numberOfSections

        // delete previous subviews (if exist)
        if let selectorContainer = self.selectorParent {
            selectorContainer.removeFromSuperview()
            self.selector?.removeFromSuperview()
            self.selectorParent = nil
            self.selector = nil
        }

        // SELECTOR CONTAINER
        let selectorContainerRect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0,
                                                   y: -borderRadius,
                                                   width: frame.width,
                                                   height: borderRadius)
        let selectorContainer = UIView(frame: selectorContainerRect)
        selectorContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        selectorContainer.AZ_roundCorners([.topLeft, .topRight], radius: borderRadius)
        selectorContainer.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.addSubview(selectorContainer)

        // SELECTOR
        let selectorRect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0,
                                          y: 0,
                                          width: selectorContainer.frame.width / CGFloat(numberOfSections),
                                          height: selectorHeight)
        let selector = UIView(frame: selectorRect)
        selector.backgroundColor = AZTheme.PaletteColor.primaryColor
        selectorContainer.addSubview(selector)

        // add views to hierarchy
        self.selectorParent = selectorContainer
        self.selector = selector
    }

    /// Animate the position of the selector passing the index of the new section
    func animateSelectorTo(sectionIndex: Int) {
        guard let selectorContainer = self.selectorParent, let selector = self.selector else { return }
        selector.layer.removeAllAnimations()

        let sectionWidth: CGFloat = selectorContainer.frame.width / CGFloat(numberOfSections)
        let newCoord = CGPoint(x: sectionWidth * CGFloat(sectionIndex), y: selector.frame.origin.y)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: { [weak self] in
            self?.selector?.frame.origin = newCoord
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
````